# How to increment a variable by 1 each time it's accessed

Tags: java, android

I'm coding a recyclerview with infinite scroll.

`int number = 1`

Let's say

`string url = "http://www.example.com?page= + 'number'"` 
is the URL of the first set of list.

Then when I'm appending the next page to the current page, the value of `number` in the `url` variable will become `2`.

Next, it'll be `3` and so on.

I'm thinking of checking the current value of `number` in `url` and then incrementing by 1 but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Maybe a for loop is better for your needs?

Comment: Please, what is the reason for the down voting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way should be making it private and creating accesors

```
private int number;

public void setNumber(int number)
{
    this.number = number
} 

public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
```

Once having this you can modify the getter so it says:

```
public int getNumber()
{
    return number++;
}
```

That will increment number by 1 each time you call getNumber()

So you can just use

```
string url = "http://www.example.com?page=" + getNumber();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since you wrote `private int number;` does this mean that the first value of `number` will be 1?

Comment: It will be 0, private or public has nothing to do with default value.

Comment: There is no page number that 's zero for the url. So shouldn't `private int number;` be `private int number = 1;` ?

Comment: If you want it to start from 1 then yes

Answer (score 1):

You could either do something like this:

```
int number = 1
[...]
String url = "http://www.example.com?page=" + (number++);
```

or create a helper method such as

```
int getNextNumber(){
  return ++number;
}
[...]
String url = "http://www.example.com?page=" + getNextNumber();
```